# Knowing when an inner Simulink subsystem is sampled

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have an outer Simulink subsystem A with a sample time of 1.0 containing an inner subsystem B with sample time 10.0. Everything works as expected; however, I require an outport for subsystem A that indicates whether subsystem B has been sampled in this step, i.e. that yields 1 every tenth step (1.0/10.0), otherwise 0 (I don't want to hardcode this with a counter, but properly get this information). Of course, it is acceptable that subsystem B passes this information via an outport to the containing subsystem A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be like this shown below. I hope the pictures are self-explaining. The model which is shown is subsystem A, with a sample time of 1s, and the atomic subsystem is subsystem B with a sample time of 10s. (Please open the picture in another tab to see the full-size model)

[image: Model]

which results in the following signal, which I believe is what you are after.

[image: Plot]